# Testing aws lambda python function with nested json

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Below is what I would like to input as my testing event and is what my lambda python function knows how to process.

```
{
  "body": '{"email":"example@example.com","password":"Example1"}',
  "path": "/SignIn"
}
```

However, you can't configure this as a testing event in aws lambda because you get the following–somewhat justified–error:

`There is an error in your JSON event. Please correct it before saving.`

It is somewhat justified because there shouldn't be any single quotes in JSON. However, it won't work if I use all double quotes either.

Any ideas? Loopholes?

Comment: JSON strings must use the double-quote as the delimiter. Is the value associated with "body" supposed to be a string, or a nested object?

Comment: If it has to be string, then try `"{\"email\":\"example@example.com\",\"password\":\"Example1\"}"`. Otherwise, just get rid of the single quotes.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @PM2Ring, that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
{
  "body": "{\"email\":\"example@example.com\",\"password\":\"Example1\"}",
  "path": "SignIn"
}
```

But then do json.loads() and get rid of the "", but ideally I will never send a password on API payload like this!